# How do you stop Linux from re-setting the display brightness?

Tags: linux, brightness, acpi

After manually setting the display brightness on my laptop, the system re-sets the value. If the laptop is plugged in, the value is set to full brightness; if it is not plugged in, it is set to dimmer. How do I stop that behavior?

Note that I am not talking about what it does in response to the event of plugging in or unplugging my system. It changes on it's own - usually several minutes after I change the brightness value. I have observed this behavior on different systems, different distributions, and different desktop environments.

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is usually controlled from the systems Power Management/Power Saving settings. How to access that depends on your flavour of linux and/or desktop system <sub><sup>(Gnome or KDE for example)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yeah, I've looked there in both Gnome and KDE to no avail. I'm hoping someone knows how to deal with ACPI in Linux at a lower level.